# Is my understanding of こと correct?

Tags: translation, nominalization

While translating a book, I noticed early on that こと is often used as a nominalizer when its placed behind a dictionary-form verb and written in hiragana. Having jumped back on the translation bandwagon during covid, I re-noticed this while looking over my early translation notes, such as the use of こと in the following excerpt from said notes.

> (1) ともかく、　逃げきることだけを考えよう。
>
> Anyhow, my only thoughts are of escape.
>
> (2) そんなことを考えてる僕の耳に、銀髪の外国人の忍{しの}び笑いが聞こえてきた。
>
> Thinking over such things, I accidently hear the silver-haired foreigner’s muffled laughter.

Is this observation of こと acting as a nominalizer if it is placed behind a dictionary-form verb and written in hiragana correct, or merely coincidental?

Edit: I am certain こと doesn't work as a nominalizer if placed behind a adjective (pre-noun adjectivals excluded from exemption), as in the second excerpt above, however, any clarification provided if my guess is wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Placed in front of an adverb?

Comment: @Leebo typo. fixed.

Comment: But you're referring to そんな, right? そんな is a pre-noun adjectival. そんなに would be an adverb.

Comment: @leebo screw my ability to get the words 'adverbs' and 'adjectives' mixed up in my native language. fixed, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking here. You are correct that こと is a nominaliser in sentence 1), and you are correct that it simply means 'thing(s)' in sentence 2).

I may have misunderstood. You seem to be suggesting that maybe こと is always a nominaliser when it comes after a verb and is never a nominaliser when it comes after an adjective. But I don't think either of these statements is generally true. For example 言ったこと could be "the thing I said" rather than "saying", and 安いこと could be "the fact that it's cheap" rather than "a cheap thing".

From a strictly grammatical point of view I don't know where to draw the line in terms of calling something a nominaliser but, personally, it doesn't help me to think in this way anyway. I just think of こと as a noun which gets modified by a relative clause. The noun can mean 'thing', 'act', 'case' etc and the context determines which is most appropriate.

In your first sentence こと may well be a nominaliser but you can just translate it as the noun 'act' in this case. What kind of act? 逃げきること = the act of escaping = escaping.

Here's an example with an adjective:

> 高いことを気にしない。
> I don't care that it's expensive.

In this sentence こと is a nominaliser but you can just think of it as the noun 'fact'. What kind of fact? The fact that it's expensive.